# What is the difference between "=" and "==" in Room queries?

Tags: android, database, sqlite, kotlin, android-room

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM table where age = :age")
fun getAge(age: Int)

@Query("DELETE FROM table where name == :name")
suspend fun deleteName(name: String): Int?
```

One query uses `=` and the other uses `==`, I wanted to know if there is any difference between them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is practically no difference, the equals operator in sqlite has two variations, from [SQL Language Expressions](https://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html)

> Note that there are two variations of the equals and not equals
> operators. Equals can be either `=` or `==`. The non-equals operator can
> be either `!=` or `<>`.

Answer (score 0):

As of now, **it now matters**.

1. For **where clause** use the double i.e **==**
2. For **set,update,delete clause** use the single i.e **=**

Comment: Do you have a reference to the documentation of this change? The SQLite documentation suggests otherwise: https://sqlite.org/lang_expr.html.